# How to parse a CSV file containing serialized PHP?

Tags: perl, csv

I've just started dabbling in Perl, to try and gain some exposure to different programming languages - so forgive me if some of the following code is horrendous.

I needed a quick and dirty CSV parser that could receive a CSV file, and split it into file batches containing "X" number of CSV lines (taking into account that entries could contain embedded newlines).

I came up with a working solution, and it was going along just fine. However, as one of the CSV files that I'm trying to split, I came across one that contains serialized PHP code.

This seems to break the CSV parsing. As soon as I remove the serialization - the CSV file is parsed correctly.

Are there any tricks I need to know when it comes to parsing serialized data in CSV files?

Here is a shortened sample of the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ eol => $/, always_quote => 1, binary => 1 });
my $out;
my $in;

open $in, "<:encoding(utf8)", "infile.csv" or die("cannot open input file $inputfile");
open $out, ">outfile.000";
binmode($out, ":utf8");
while (my $line = $csv->getline($in)) {
    $lines++;
    $csv->print($out, $line);
}
```

I'm never able to get into the `while` loop shown above. As soon as I remove the serialized data, I suddenly am able to get into the loop.

**Edit:**

An example of a line that is causing me trouble (taken straight from Vim - hence the ^M):

```
"26","other","1","20,000 Subscriber Plan","Some text here.^M\
Some more text","on","","18","","0","","0","0","recurring","0","","payment","totalsend","0","tsadmin","R34bL9oq","37","0","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","0","0","a:18:{i:0;s:1:\"3\";i:1;s:1:\"2\";i:2;s:2:\"59\";i:3;s:2:\"60\";i:4;s:2:\"61\";i:5;s:2:\"62\";i:6;s:2:\"63\";i:7;s:2:\"64\";i:8;s:2:\"65\";i:9;s:2:\"66\";i:10;s:2:\"67\";i:11;s:2:\"68\";i:12;s:2:\"69\";i:13;s:2:\"70\";i:14;s:2:\"71\";i:15;s:2:\"72\";i:16;s:2:\"73\";i:17;s:2:\"74\";}","","","0","0","","0","0","0.0000","0.0000","0","","","0.00","","6","1"
"27","other","1","35,000 Subscriber Plan","Some test here.^M\
Some more text","on","","18","","0","","0","0","recurring","0","","payment","totalsend","0","tsadmin","R34bL9oq","38","0","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","0","0","a:18:{i:0;s:1:\"3\";i:1;s:1:\"2\";i:2;s:2:\"59\";i:3;s:2:\"60\";i:4;s:2:\"61\";i:5;s:2:\"62\";i:6;s:2:\"63\";i:7;s:2:\"64\";i:8;s:2:\"65\";i:9;s:2:\"66\";i:10;s:2:\"67\";i:11;s:2:\"68\";i:12;s:2:\"69\";i:13;s:2:\"70\";i:14;s:2:\"71\";i:15;s:2:\"72\";i:16;s:2:\"73\";i:17;s:2:\"74\";}","","","0","0","","0","0","0.0000","0.0000","0","","","0.00","","7","1"
"28","other","1","50,000 Subscriber Plan","Some text here.^M\
Some more text","on","","18","","0","","0","0","recurring","0","","payment","totalsend","0","tsadmin","R34bL9oq","39","0","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","0","0","a:18:{i:0;s:1:\"3\";i:1;s:1:\"2\";i:2;s:2:\"59\";i:3;s:2:\"60\";i:4;s:2:\"61\";i:5;s:2:\"62\";i:6;s:2:\"63\";i:7;s:2:\"64\";i:8;s:2:\"65\";i:9;s:2:\"66\";i:10;s:2:\"67\";i:11;s:2:\"68\";i:12;s:2:\"69\";i:13;s:2:\"70\";i:14;s:2:\"71\";i:15;s:2:\"72\";i:16;s:2:\"73\";i:17;s:2:\"74\";}","","","0","0","","0","0","0.0000","0.0000","0","","","0.00","","8","1""73","other","8","10,000,000","","","","0","","0","","0","0","recurring","0","","payment","","0","","","75","0","10000000","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","0","0","0","a:17:{i:0;s:1:\"3\";i:1;s:1:\"2\";i:2;s:2:\"59\";i:3;s:2:\"60\";i:4;s:2:\"61\";i:5;s:2:\"62\";i:6;s:2:\"63\";i:7;s:2:\"64\";i:8;s:2:\"65\";i:9;s:2:\"66\";i:10;s:2:\"67\";i:11;s:2:\"68\";i:12;s:2:\"69\";i:13;s:2:\"70\";i:14;s:2:\"71\";i:15;s:2:\"72\";i:16;s:2:\"74\";}","","","0","0","","0","0","0.0000","0.0000","0","","","0.00","","14","0"
```

Comment: If your CSV parser is standards-compliant, and your CSV file is also standards-compliant, then it will "just work". Otherwise, you'll have to write  a bug-for-bug compatible parser.

Comment: Can you include an example of problematic row?

Comment: @JanHudec, added example line data.

Comment: So now we can see which flavour of CSV it is. Because there is no single CSV standard as @tylerl suggests. There are various flavours and you have slightly different from what `Text::CSV_XS` expects by default. But it can be configured using the constructor parameters.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't realise the difference between the two sites until you asked this question. Thanks for making me realise the difference.

Comment: @gnat: Why didn't you join the vote to migrate?

Comment: @JanHudec because he's almost always out of migrate votes by this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSV you are trying to read escapes embedded quotes with backslash, but the default for [`Text::CSV_XS`](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.01/CSV_XS.pm#new) is to escape by doubling them. Try adding `escape_char => '\\'` to the `Text::CSV_XS` constructor.

You may also need `allow_loose_escapes => 1` if it uses backslash to quote other things that don't strictly need it like newlines.

The other option is to change the writer to use doubled quotes instead of backslashes for escaping. Might or might not be possible. Doubling the quotes is the more common flavour of CSV and while programmatic parsers can generally read both (if told), you won't be able to read the variant with backslash e.g. in Excel.

Comment: I still seem to be running into issues with embedded newlines and carriage returns, strangely enough.

I'll update the question with more sample data. I don't think one line is enough.

Comment: @garbetjie: Try adding `allow_loose_escapes`. And _read_ the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.01/CSV_XS.pm#new) (the parameters you pass seem to be copied from somewhere and don't make much sense for parsing).

Comment: It seems like that works, thanks. I did read the documentation on it - but clearly not thoroughly enough. Are you able to provide any insight as to _why_ this would make the difference? What is so special about the CR that would break parsing?

Comment: @garbetjie: It's too ordinary. The parser does not expect it to be escaped, because within quotes it does not have to be. And by default complains about it. So you have to tell it to ignore unnecessary escapes.